# SQL Server 2005 trigger not working

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table called as `order_details` and another one as `book_inventory`.

When ever i i `quantity_ordered` in `order_details` it should reduce that value from `quantity_in_stock` from `book_inventory`.

Here is my code:

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[book]
   ON  [dbo].[order_details]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 

IF UPDATE(quantity_ordered)
    UPDATE book_inventory
    SET    book_inventory.quantity_in_stock = book_inventory.quantity_in_stock - order_details.quantity_ordered
    FROM   order_details
    WHERE book_inventory.isbn = order_details.isbn
```

Comment: meanwhile - you not use the INSERTED and DELETED aliases in trigger - its an intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seemes to me that the proper way to write this query will be

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[book]
   ON  [dbo].[order_details]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 

IF UPDATE(quantity_ordered)
    UPDATE book_inventory
    SET    book_inventory.quantity_in_stock = book_inventory.quantity_in_stock - i.quantity_ordered + d.quantity_ordered 
    FROM   INSERTED i
    JOIN DELETED d
      ON d.isbn = i.isbn
    WHERE book_inventory.isbn = i.isbn
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. the problem is am a begineer and dont know where to apply the trigger. what i did was open sql server 2005, create new query and executed the code
but when i entered the values through my front end in asp.net the values in book_inventory dint change
Will be great if u can help me out